# form.cleaned_data is while form handling

Tags: django, forms, cleaned-data

It's a really simple form but I don't know where's got wrong. When I check the debug mode of django site, I found that the clean_data of `new` field is missing, as the picture of following:

[image: cleaned_data['new'] is missing]

```
class PasswordEditForm(forms.Form):
  old = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6,
                      max_length=30, label='舊密碼', label_suffix=' ')
  new = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6,
                      max_length=30,  label='新密碼', label_suffix=' ')
  new_confirm = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, min_length=6,
                              max_length=30,  label='再輸入一次', label_suffix=' ')

  def clean_new(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['old'] == cd['new']:
      raise forms.ValidationError('新密碼與舊密碼相同')
    return cd['new']

  def clean_new_confirm(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    if cd['new'] != cd['new_confirm']:
      raise forms.ValidationError('兩次輸入密碼不相符')
    return cd['new_confirm']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if you type same new and old password then `clean_new` method raise exception and return no value. That's why in `clean_new_confirm` which performed after `clean_new` cleaned_data is not contains `new` value.

You can avoid error just using `get`. Check first if cleaned_data contains `new` value and if yes, check if `new` equals to `new_confirm`:

```
def clean_new_confirm(self):
    cd = self.cleaned_data
    new_pass = cd.get('new')
    if new_pass and new_pass != cd.get('new_confirm'):
        raise forms.ValidationError('兩次輸入密碼不相符')
    return cd['new_confirm']
```